# Computing ramification of a curve using duality of projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to do exercise IV.2.3(a) in Hartshorne but I am having trouble understanding how to proceed.

First, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a projective plane curve which is nonsingular. Then, $X = V(f)$ for some $f \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}(d))$, so that by nonsingularity the linear system $V = \langle \partial f/ \partial x_0, \partial f/ \partial x_1, \partial f/ \partial x_3\rangle \subset \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(d - 1))$ is basepoint free, and defines a morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^2$, whose image is the dual curve $X^\vee \subset (\mathbb{P}^2)^\vee$. That is, a point $P \in X$ gets mapped to the point in $(\mathbb{P}^2)^\vee$ corresponding to the tangent line to $X$ at $P$, denoted $T_PX$.

Now we fix a line $L$ which doest coincide with any tangent line of $X$. That is, the point $L^\vee$ is not contained in $X^\vee$. We then define a map $\varphi: X \to L$ which sends a point $P$ to the point in the intersection $L \cap T_P X$. I want to show that $\varphi$ is ramified at $P$ if and only if $P \in L$ or $T_P X$ has intersection multiplicity $\geq 3$ with $X$.

I'm very stuck on this point, since I don't know how to describe $\varphi^*$ on local rings, or to show it's even a morphism. The main thing I've attempted is to count the number of points in the intersection and relate this to the number of points in the preimage but this hasn't been very fruitful. The main idea is that if we have less than $d$ points $Q_1, Q_2, \dots, Q_r$ in the preimage of $P$, then we see that $P^\vee$ is a line intersecting $X^\vee$ at exactly the points $L^\vee$, $T_{Q_i}X^\vee$. I haven't been able to get much farther than this, though.

If you all have any advice on how to think about this problem, and how to effectively do this kind of computation I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one where you actually have to do a little more "geometry" than maybe has been going on with the rest of the book so far. Here's something to get you started: pick coordinates so that $P=[0:0:1]$ and both $T_PX$ and $L$ are convenient (there are two scenarios: $P\in L$ or not). Then calculate the intersection of the tangent line with $L$, and after some fiddling you'll get an actual formula for the map which you can investigate with on local rings. (Let me know if this isn't enough - I can add a full answer later.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out, but I think it should be enough. I may add a full answer once I work the details out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to fix notation, we want to study the ramification of $X = \{f = 0\}$ at $P \in X$. Let $x, y, z$ be the coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Let's consider $P \notin L$.  Applying an automorphism we take $L = \{z = 0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ the line at infinity, $T_pX = \{x = 0\}$, and $P = [0,0,1]$. In this case the point of intersection is $[0: 1: 0].$ Let's calculate what $\varphi$ is for arbitrary $Q = [a: b: 1] \notin L$. Then tangent line is $$T_QX = \left\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x - az) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y - bz) = 0\right\}$$
so the point of intersection is exactly $[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(Q):  -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(Q): 0]$. In particular we see that $\varphi|_{\mathbb{A}^2}: X \cap \mathbb{A}^2 \to L$ is the map given by pulling back $\varphi^*x = \partial f/ \partial y$ and $\varphi^*y = -\partial f/ \partial x$. As such, the map $\mathcal{O}_{L, [0,1,0]} \to \mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ is given by $\frac{x}{y} \mapsto -\frac{\partial f/\partial y}{ \partial f/ \partial x}$, so that this $\varphi$ ramified at $P$ if and only if $\nu_P(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) \geq 2$.

Now unraveling the definitions, we see that $\nu_P(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ is the order of vanishing of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y, 1)$ the origin of $X \cap \mathbb{A}^2$ On the other hand, the intersection multiplicity of $T_PX$ and $X$ at $P$ is the dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}/(x)$. Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0,1) \neq 0$, we may write $f(x,y,1) = cx + g(x,y) y^l$ for $c \neq 0$, $l > 0$ and $g(0,0) \neq 0$. As such, $y$ is a uniformizing parameter for $X$ at $P$ and $$\mathcal{O}_{X, P}/(x) = (k[y]_{(y)}/(g(0,y)y^l)) = k[y]_{(y)}/(y^l)$$ since $g(0,y)$ is a unit in $k[y]_{(y)}$.

With $f$ written as above we see that, $\nu_P(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) = l - 1$. On the other hand, $\dim_k \mathcal{O}_{X< P}/(x) = l$ so that $$\nu_P(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) + 1 = \dim_k \mathcal{O}_{X, P}/(x) = i(X, T_PX; P).$$ This then gives the required equivalence.

Now consider the case when $P \in L$. By applying an automorphism of $(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$ we may assume $L = \{y = 0\}$ and $T_PX = \{x = 0\}$, so that $P = (0,0)$. To find the ramification we compute note that for $Q = (a,b) \in \mathbb{A}^2$, the map is given by $Q \mapsto a + m(Q)b$, where $m(Q) = \frac{\partial f/\partial y}{\partial f/ \partial x}(Q)$. As such, to compute the ramification we find the order of vanishing of the function $x + m(x,y)y$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ at $0.$

Now, $m(0,0) = 0$, so that $\nu_P(m(x,y) y) \geq 2$ is immediate. Hence we just need to show $\nu_P(x) \geq 2$ as well to see that $P$ is ramified. To see this note that $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x}(0,0) \neq 0$ whereas $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}(0,0) = 0$ so $f \in cx + \mathfrak{m}^2_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}$  for $c \neq 0$, which implies that in $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$, we have $x \in \mathfrak{m}_{X, P}^2$ as required.

This concludes the proof that $P$ is ramified if and only if $P \in L$ or $P$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Good work, this looks correct to me :)